MODBUS protocol implementation over RS485 for HMI LCD
I am planning to use PICCOLO microcontroller where HMI lcd will be interfaced over RS485 lines. UART lines of microcontroller will be interfaced to LCD via MAX22501 Transceiver.
My query is can we implement MODBUS protocol over RS485 lines with hardware which I will be developing or anything more should be taken care in hardware?
Link for LCD datasheet attached for reference.
Schematic:

Thank you.

What do you mean "can we implement MODBUS protocol over RS485 lines with hardware"? Obviously not, that is implemented in software. Why would you pick old MODBUS over some CAN solution, however? Do you need to be backwards-compatible with some old device?

Techknowlogic, MOSBUS uses RS485 as its physical layer so, when you ask "can we implement MODBUS protocol over RS485 lines" it seems you haven't done any basic research.

@Andy aka - You are correct. I am aware on that part. My question is related to hardware interface where I used MCU- MAX3483-LCD connection.
Question : Is the hardware interface scheme mentioned here is correct or anything is missed?

@Lundin Right it is implemented in firmware. But I am concerned now on the hardware part. And therefore want to be sure that anything is not missed on board.

Without a schematic over the transceiver circuit you've made, it is hard to say anything about that. Also it depends on requirements such as expected baudrate, EMC, cable distances.

@Techknowlogic We can't aswer the question if your hardware can do it or not, as you present no hardware or connections between chips or anything. Simply by saying the RS-485 chip type tells nothing except that it could be used if done correctly.

@Andyaka  , Justme , Lundin : updated schematic for clarity

@Techknowlogic what has the circuit you added got to do with the LCD and the MAX3483?

@Andyaka - Sorry for little confusion here. MAX22501 shown in image is alternative to MAX3483.
J14 is a connector for HMI LCD and J13 is a connection with microcontroller.
MAX22501 is transceiver IC used for level conversion to RS485.

RS-485, even though it uses two wires for differential communication, it does rely on a somewhat common ground. This is to keep the common mode voltage within limits.
If you cannot provide this between nodes, at least one of them needs to be galvanically isolated.
The manual says the HMI supports both HMI as Master and HMI as Slave for modbus.
Since MODBUS only supports a single master node, choose carefully.

Please see schematic where transceiver is added for level conversion.
